# Mysql left join and get different data

Tags: mysql, left-join

I would like to get a different record from the left join sql.

```
SELECT sd.bill_amount, mr.payment_amount 
FROM event_mgmt_settlement_details sd 
LEFT JOIN event_mgmt_registration mr 
ON sd.order_id = mr.order_id
```

In this sql, I can get all the records from 2 tables with same order_id, but some sd.order_id or mr.order_id that have unique id that each other don't have, how I can get those records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to find the unmatch record from both table is to do a `union all` and then select data with `group_by`. This way works well if the tables are having the same column names. Since you have different names then it needs some adjustment and perhaps better to make an identity to see from which table the record is coming.

```
select 
order_id,
amount,
table_name
from
(
  select 
  order_id,
  bill_amount as amount,
  'Table1' as table_name
  from event_mgmt_settlement_details
  union all
  select 
  order_id,
  payment_amount as amount,
  'Table2' as table_name
  from event_mgmt_registration
)x
GROUP BY order_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3818a/3)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sd.bill_amount, mr.payment_amount 
FROM event_mgmt_settlement_details sd , event_mgmt_registration mr
```

Comment: I tried this, 
let's say sd.order_id have 1 to 11 and mr.order_id have 1 to 10. 
the id will become 
1:1
2:1
3:1
until 11:10

Comment: just remove left join ok. you can select from to table at once. like that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT sd.bill_amount, mr.payment_amount 
FROM event_mgmt_settlement_details sd ,event_mgmt_registration mr
```

so if you have sd.order_id have 1 to 11 and mr.order_id have 1 to 10 the result is:

1 : 1,
2 : 1,
3 : 1,
etc ..
11 : 10

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT sd.order_id, sd.bill_amount, 'event_mgmt_settlement_details'
  FROM event_mgmt_settlement_details sd 
  LEFT JOIN event_mgmt_registration mr  
    ON sd.order_id = mr.order_id
 WHERE mr.order_id is null
 UNION ALL
SELECT mr.order_id, mr.payment_amount, 'event_mgmt_registration'
  FROM event_mgmt_settlement_details sd 
 RIGHT JOIN event_mgmt_registration mr  
    ON sd.order_id = mr.order_id
 WHERE sd.order_id is null
```

Since MySql doesn't support full outer join, union left join and right join instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider the following schema for different [join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) types:
[image: you can consider the following schema for different join types]

```
SELECT sd.bill_amount, mr.payment_amount 
FROM event_mgmt_settlement_details sd 
FULL OUTER JOIN event_mgmt_registration mr 
ON sd.order_id = mr.order_id
WHERE sd.order_id IS NULL OR mr.order_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: MySql doesn't support full outer join.

Comment: @JaugarChang  You don't have FULL JOINS on MySQL THEN TRY [UNION LEFT JOIN & RIGHT JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)